# Trying to add contents of cells that all relate to same month

Tags: excel-formula

Hi I have a column with dates & a column next to it with numbers. I want to be able to sum the numbers that all relate to the same month.  I have tried SUMIF but can't work out how to get the criteria part working, I found a page suggesting the use of MATCH & MONTH but it wasn't very clear & now I'm just confused.  Can anybody offer any assistance please.

| Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 7 Aug | 44 |
| 14 Aug | 27 |
| 4 Sep | 61 |
| 11 Sep | 29 |

Example Results    Aug 71, Sep 90

=sumif(_date, ?,_quantity)

Comment: I have solved it using following formula  =SUMIFS(_QUANTITY,_DATE,">="&(B32),_DATE,"<="&EOMONTH(B32,0))  where B32 is a cell with date entered as 1/8/22 formatted to mmm so it just shows Aug

Comment: Good comment, @Donna. I would advise to use `"<"&EDATE(B32,1)` for the second condition. Reason is that if the date values include time then any value past from 0:01 to 23:59 will be excluded for the last day of the month, because it's greater than the day value itself (which would include 0 time, being 0:00)

Comment: You can also use a formula like this `=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT($A$2:$A$5,"mmm-yyyy")=TEXT(A2,"mmm-yyyy"))*$B$2:$B$5)`

Answer (score 0):

The best function here is `SUMPRODUCT` -

[image]